# Время ожидания ответа requests.get в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Можно ли как-то задать время ожидания ответа от страницы при использовании `requests.get('https://site.name')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
requests.get(url, timeout=2.5)  # время в секундах
```

Учитесь пользоваться [документацией](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts).